# How to place 2 Jlabel object into a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jlabel

I am pretty new in Java Swing and I have the following problem:

I have a class named **LoginFrame** that have to show a **JFrame** object containing a login form:

```
package com.techub.crystalice.gui.login;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;

import com.techub.crystalice.gui.Constants;
import com.techub.crystalice.gui.GUI;


public class LoginFrame extends SingleFrameApplication {

    @Override
    protected void startup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("DENTRO: LoginFrame() ---> startup()");

        JFrame loginFrame = this.getMainFrame();
        Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(400, 250);
        loginFrame.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);
        loginFrame.setTitle("XCloud Login");

        JLabel userName = new JLabel("Username:");
        JLabel pswd = new JLabel("Password:");

        loginFrame.add(userName);
        loginFrame.add(pswd);

        show(loginFrame);

        //show(new JLabel("Hello World"));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("DENTRO: LoginFrame() ---> main()");
        launch(LoginFrame.class, args);
    }

}
```

The abstrac class **SingleFrameApplication** automatically provide me the **JFrame** object on which I set some property (dimension and title).

Then I have try to add 2 **JLabel** object that respectively show the string "Username:" and "Password:**

The problem is that in this way it only show the string "Password" in the center (vertically) of the JFrame and not both one below the other.

Why? How can I put 2 JLabel and how can I place them in the correct way inside my JFrame?

What am I missing?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution: put the JLabels in a JPanel, and then put that JPanel into the JFrame.

Longer answer: your problem is with layouts. A JFrame (or more correctly, its contentPane) uses a BorderLayout by default, and when you add a component to it without using int constant co-parameters, you place the component by default into the BorderLayout.CENTER position. The last component added will cover all components added previously. A JPanel however uses the FlowLayout by default, and all components added to it will be added one after the other according to the rules of FlowLayout.

The key to all this is to read the [tutorial on how to use Swing layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and then play with them to better learn to use them.